# vector destroys objects but does not construct their replacements?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, destructor, push-back

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class cMember
{
    public: 
    int id;

    cMember();
    ~cMember();
};

cMember::cMember()
{
    cout<<"member constructor\n";
}

cMember::~cMember() 
{
    cout<<"member destructor\n";
};

class cDirectory
{
    std::vector<cMember> memberList;

public:
    cDirectory();
    ~cDirectory();

    void Populate();
};


cDirectory::cDirectory()
{
    cout<<"directory constructor\n";
}

cDirectory::~cDirectory()
{
    cout<<"directory desctructor\n";
}

void cDirectory::Populate()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        cout<<"A\n";
        cMember t;
        memberList.push_back(t);
        cout<<"B\n";
    }
    cout<<"C\n";
}

int main( int argc, const char ** argv )
{
    cDirectory dir;
    dir.Populate();
    exit(0);
}
```

Looking at the output of this program, the second iteration calls the members destructor between A and B. I assume this call is the vector reallocating and repopulating, and destroying the members it had in it before the reallocation.

How can vector be destroying objects, but not constructing their replacements?

Comment: Read up on the "rule of 3".  You should have a copy constructor and assignment operator instrumented in your classes as well.

Comment: as you were told, vector makes a deep copy by calling the copy constructor

Comment: If you want to call the default constructor and not the copy constructor, you can `emplace()` the new elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `cMember` is statically allocated, when the function goes out of scope that memory would be lost. This would be problematic for the vector if it still had a reference to that point in memory. So instead, `std::vector` will copy construct that object. This gives the vector its own dynamically allocated copy, which will exist for the vector even after the function goes out of scope.

I modified your code to print `this` as well, and this is the output:

```
directory constructor
A
member constructor 0x7fff572e86f8
B
member destructor 0x7fff572e86f8
A
member constructor 0x7fff572e86f8
member destructor 0x7fc1dbc04c80
B
member destructor 0x7fff572e86f8
C
```

As you can see, the object being destroyed between A and B was not constructed by your functions. Instead, it was the copy constructed object used by the `std::vector`.

Comment: This answer makes sense, but my question came up because the actual situation is a little more complex than the code example I posted. Add a pointer to cMember and delete it in the destructor, and that becomes an issue. Sorry about not making that clear in the original question. Is there a typical way of handling this?

Comment: You'll want to write a custom copy constructor, and in that copy constructor, allocate new memory for the copy (instead of just assigning the pointer). Alternatively if you don't want to allocate more memory each time and the two objects should be using the same pointer (just without the deallocation problem) you could consider using smart pointers from C++11: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr

Comment: I think I've avoided this whole issue by just never pushing a statically allocated object. I've always used vectors of pointers and a cleanup routine when the objects pointed to are no longer needed. Thanks for your explanations and solutions!

Answer (score 5):

> How can vector be destroying objects, but not constructing their
>   replacements?

It constructs them via calling the **copy constructor** of the object and not the user defined default one.

That is, if you don't define one copy constructor for an object the compiler is going to implicitly define one for you. This is the case also here. When your vector's buffer gets re-allocated the copy constructor of each object is evoked in order to copy the objects in their new location. You can see this if you define the copy constructor as follows:

```
class cMember {
public: 
  int id;
  cMember();
  CMember(cMember const&);
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ~cMember();
};

cMember::cMember(cMember const &) {
    cout<<"member copy constructor\n";
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73323ef25f883e1b)